# Set values fetched from api in react hooks form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am using React Hook form, so my concern in how do i set data to input fields in react hooks forms as of now for posting data my structure is like

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="stacked">Full Name</IonLabel>
             

              <Controller
                render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
                  <IonInput
                   
                    onIonChange={onChange}
                  />
                )}
                control={control}
                name="email"
                defaultValue={state.name}
                value={state.name}
                rules={{
                  required: true,
                  pattern: {
                    value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                    message: "invalid email address",
                  },
                }}
              />
              {_.get("email.type", errors) === "pattern" && (
                <p className="errorWarning">CHeck email</p>
              )}
            </IonItem>
</form>
```

but what if i had to use the same thing and set its value to something which i get from my api?

For checking purposr i tried to initalize my state with some value like

> state:{name:'yourname'}

but then when i try to sett this value in the form by using defaultValue props and value props , none of them works even though console.log(state.name) gives me 'yourfullname'

```
 <Controller
                render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
                  <IonInput
                   
                    onIonChange={onChange}
                  />
                )}
                control={control}
                name="email"
                defaultValue={state.name}
                value={state.name}
                rules={{
                  required: true,
                  pattern: {
                    value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                    message: "invalid email address",
                  },
                }}
              />
```

Comment: Are you using Redux?

Comment: yes i will eventually get all data from my redux state

Comment: Cool, Hold while I answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redux, after mapping your API data from state to props in your component.

On component mount, you need to fetch needed data using the useEffect hook, in the same function, check if the prop(data) is available, if it is then use the setState or similar to set your API data to the data in your component level state. By checking if the prop is available and has data you can be sure the data you need returns before you try to use it in your form.

You can then pass the data from your state to your form value or default value.

```js
const [values, setvalues] = useState({
  name: ''
})

 useEffect(() => {
    async function loadData() {
      await apRequest()
    }
    loadData()
  }, [])

useEffect(() => {
  if(apiData) {
    setValues({
      name: apiData.name,
    })
  }
}, [apiData])

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="stacked">Full Name</IonLabel>
             

              <Controller
                render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
                  <IonInput
                   
                    onIonChange={onChange}
                  />
                )}
                control={control}
                name="email"
                defaultValue={values.name}
                value={values.name}
                rules={{
                  required: true,
                  pattern: {
                    value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                    message: "invalid email address",
                  },
                }}
              />
              {_.get("email.type", errors) === "pattern" && (
                <p className="errorWarning">CHeck email</p>
              )}
            </IonItem>
</form>
```

Remember you are getting apiRequest() and apiData from `props`

You can try this and tweak a few things

Comment: but then why when i manually initialized the state with static data , i wasnt showing up in the input value and now it will show? getting confused :)